# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make an greetings image, when new user joins my server.

I have index.js and generateImage.js, where generates this image.

That`s generateImage.js

```
const generateImage = async (member) => {
    
    let username = member.user.username
    let discrim = member.user.discriminator
    let avatarURL = member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png", dynamic: false, size: av.size})

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(dim.width, dim.height)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

    const backimg = await Canvas.loadImage(clanimage)
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.55
    ctx.drawImage(backimg, 0, 0, dim.width, dim.height)

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage(wtimage);
    ctx.save()
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(bg.x + bg.radius, bg.y);
    ctx.lineTo(bg.x + 999 - bg.radius, bg.y);
    ctx.arcTo(bg.x + 999, bg.y, bg.x + 999, bg.y + bg.radius, bg.radius);
    ctx.lineTo(bg.x + 999, bg.y + 554 - bg.radius);
    ctx.arcTo(bg.x + 999, bg.y + 554, bg.x + 999 - bg.radius, bg.y + 554, bg.radius);
    ctx.lineTo(bg.x + bg.radius, bg.y + 554);
    ctx.arcTo(bg.x, bg.y + 554, bg.x, bg.y + 554 - bg.radius, bg.radius);
    ctx.lineTo(bg.x, bg.y + bg.radius);
    ctx.arcTo(bg.x, bg.y, bg.x + bg.radius, bg.y, bg.radius);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(background,bg.x, bg.y, 999, 554);
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1
    const avimg = await Canvas.loadImage(avatarURL)
    ctx.save()
    
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(av.x + av.size / 2, av.y + av.size / 2, av.size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.clip()

    ctx.drawImage(avimg, av.x, av.y)
    ctx.restore()

    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.textAlign = "center"

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1


    const attachment = {files: [canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome.png"]}
    return attachment 
}
```

And that is index.js

```
const welcomeChannelId = "1016310734977777697";
import generateImage from "./commands/generateImage.js";

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {

    const img = await generateImage(member)
    member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId).send({
        content: `Welcome, <@${member.id}>`,
        files: [img]
    }) 
})
```

I get an error only when `files: [img]` are in the code, so it seems to me that problem is int that
Maybe there are some new syntaxis things in discord.j, which I didn`t know.

Comment: You are trying to send something like this: `files: [{files: [canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome.png"]}]` doesn't look right to me

Comment: I can change this line of code to ``const attachment = new Attachment(canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome.png")`` and add Attachment module, but nothing will change

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Any new ideas?